# Bind TextView text sizes to another TextView size

Tags: android, android-layout, binding

I have two `TextView` controls on my layout.
User can change text size of first one by pinching.
I need the text size of second control to change every time first one changes.
In other word I want to bind same property of two different controls.

Comment: are you using `onTouchEvent` for the pinched zoom? if so what is the problem of also setting the other `TextView` size in `onTouchEvent`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in these two ways,

1. you can create a custom `listener` for you `TextView`
2. Call `setTextSize(size);` for both `Textview`

like 
`text1.setTextSize(size);`

`text2.setTextSize(size);`

Answer (score 0):

Create a subclassed textview and override [onSizeChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method to resize the other textview.

```
protected void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
```

This is called during layout when the size of this view has changed.
 If you were just added to the view hierarchy, you're called with the
 old values of 0.